# Grails & Ajax-can't succeed pass data through the controller

Tags: ajax, grails, controller

I use ajax.
In the ajax I call an action in a controller which render back:

```
render template : 'eventInvited', model : [eventInvitees :userData.get('users'),eventUsersCount:userData.get('userCounts'),
event :event, tab : userData.get('tab'), isFilter : false,user:user,flag: params.flag]
```

I have to use the eventInvitees to update some span, so in the success(ajax) I use:

```
$('.inviteeSize').html(data.eventInvitees);
```

It doesn't update this span

Comment: Can you please show some more code of your AJAX call and what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is

```
$('.inviteeSize').html(${eventInvitees});
```

or

```
$('.inviteeSize').html(${data.eventInvitees});
```

Also note that depending on the data type of eventInvitees, and what you want in the HTML, it may be better to do:

```
$('.inviteeSize').html("${eventInvitees}");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `data` argument in `success` will be HTML. You can't access the model you used to render the template in the controller this way.

You might be better performing two ajax calls, one to render the template and another to fetch a JSON object with your event invitees and any other data you need.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "...",
    dataType: "html"
}).done(function(html){
    $('.inviteeSize').html(html);
});

$.ajax({
    url: "...",
    dataType: "json"
}).done(function(json){
    console.log(json);
});
```

Some other approaches are

- Storing event invitee data in [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) in the template. Which you can then access with the `$.data` method. N.B. You can store JSON within data attributes.
- Fetching the JSON first with the invitees, then requesting the rendered template using some of the data as parameters so that you don't make the same userData.get() calls twice.
- Fetching the JSON data and then using a Javascript template engine to render HTML from this. Instead of using the Grails gsp templates.